# Change decimal number directly into hour in Excel

Tags: excel, validation

I need to convert lots of numbers that represent hours, into actual Excel values formatted like hours.

In e.g., I have a cell that has the value "16.30", and I need it to be "16:30".

I tried replacing the dot with two dots, formatting the cells with a custom format like "00:00" and "hh:mm", but nothing works. Excel returns an error or changes the value of the hour by converting the numeric value into an hour, as usual.

Any ideas about how to achieve the goal listed above?

**TL;DR:** how to change a cell with a value "16.30" into "16:30" as an hour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just typed 16.30 into Excel, changed it to 16:30, formatted the cell as "time", and it was converted automatically.

Comment: @m69 my guess is he has more than one and wants to create a formula so he can copy it down and do it all at once without having to manually change each cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner I understood from the question that he already managed to replace the dots by colons, but it's not completely clear what was tried and how exactly.

Comment: @m69 I can see that interpretation.

Comment: @m69 Sorry if I wasn't specific enough. I replaced the dots by colons using the Find and Replace Command, but that returns another number (don't know what it corresponds to). If I turn that number's cell into hour format, it obviates a number. In e.g., I take the number 10.30 and replace the dot by colons, then format the cell as hour and I get 10:03.

Comment: You're right; I probably tried with something like 16.45, and so didn't notice the 30 -> 03 problem. Sorry for the misleading comment.

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you?  If so please mark it as correct.  Click on the green check mark by the answer you used.  It is something only you can do.  It will mark this question as being answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
=TIME(INT(H6),(H6-INT(H6))*100,0)
```

Where H6 is your cell.  Then format it as you want.

Comment: It is always good to have more than one way to approach a problem. I suspect that your first way (involving `INT`) is preferable since it is probably less sensitive to rounding issues

Answer (score 2):

One way to make your idea of substituting ":" for "." work is like this:

```
=TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"0.00"),".",":"))
```

if A1 contains 16.3 and A2 contains the above and is formatted as time then it will display as time.